# Feature selection and interpretation for black box classification systems

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection

I just did terribly in an interview. One of the questions that came up was (paraphrased):

> Say you have a binary classifier, a neural net or a random forest, and
>   a dataset with huge dimensions. What would you do to select the
>   features that are most important and how would you explain how these
>   features affect the outcome. i.e. the relationship.

The model is too deep and complex to analyse the weights and such.